# How common is it to use the term "overland" to refer to transport by either land or sea only excluding flying?

Tags: meaning, colloquialisms, context

I know I've personally used the term "overland" in the context of travel to mean travelling by any means other than air travel. In fact I thought I picked up this usage by seeing others use it this way.

But when I look it up, dictionaries do seem to say "overland" does not include travel by sea.

So is it just me or is it a case of a colloquial usage that's relatively established and widespread but just not acknowledged by dictionaries?

Comment: Interesting. I found a book from before the era of aircraft that seems to use "overland" to mean "not completely by sea": [*Narrative of a journey overland from England by the continent of Europe, Egypt and the Red Sea, to India*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5vdR-eVGtP8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=overland&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOhb7114XLAhXC6x4KHfe8B6YQ6AEITTAG#v=onepage&q=overland&f=false) Even though there is some water travel, it seems to contrast here with an "overseas" journey. It would seem odd to me to use "overland" to refer to a journey that takes place entirely over the seas.

Comment: I think _surface_ does a better job than _overland_ of indicating that transportation occurs on land or on water, but not underground, underwater, or through the air.

Comment: I've personally used the term overland as well, on many different occasions.   I guess we are both colloquial.

Answer (score 3):

If it is colloquial, it's probably regional.

Have a look at this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overland&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Coverland%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boverland%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOverland%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOVERLAND%3B%2Cc0)

Overland can be cited going back to the 1600's in travel-log literature, where it seems to be distinctly stories of "I went somewhere exotic, and I took the land route".

But it remains a pretty rare word, until the 1800's. From there it sees a major surge because of [The Overland Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overland_Trail) and [the Butterfield Overland Mail/Stage Co.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfield_Overland_Mail)

Both of which strictly mean "the land route". (Sorry)

Most of the "Overland" place names in the US have their roots directly in being trail stops (and not really having much else exciting going on at the time).
In any case "correct use" of overland to describe a journey has returned to being pretty rare. If you do a google search stripping out all the place names and company names, it almost doesn't exist; and "incorrect use" has to be a super small subset of that.

So chances are if you're using it AT ALL, you're already in a group that doesn't care if it's in the dictionary or not. Embrace the fact that you're keeping alive a weird old remnant of history when traveling great distance by road was exotic and dangerous.

Comment: +1  As for embedding, [word or phrase](location)

Comment: It does have a current niche usage that seems to be on the rise for a species of adventure travelling. It's even gained a verb or at least present participle or gerund "overlanding". I know overlanders avoid flying but I'm not sure if they also avoid ferries etc or if they focus on inland adventures such as passing mountain ranges. They might not even all use it the same way. I've also seen people use "surface travel" but that has no panache so might not be gaining. I'm not sure (-:

Comment: Very nice, if you want to edit those notes into my answer I'll happily approve it.